# Incorrect output from Delivery Class for Shipping Charge Program

Tags: java, class, output

So I had the whole program written but got incorrect output for my delivery charge.  I deleted what I had written down to just one calculation to see what I was doing wrong, but still cant figure it out.  The directions were as follows:

You are hired by Expressimo Delivery Service to develop an application that computes the delivery charge. The company allows two types of packaging-letter and box- and three types of service – next day priority, next day standard, and 2-day/ the following table shows the formula for the computing charge.
Package type              Next day priority      Next day standard 2 day 
Letter $12 up to 8 oz    $10.50 up to 8 oz         Not available 
Box $15.75 for the first pound. Add $1.25 for each additional pound over the first pound. $13.75 for the first pound. Add $1.00 for each additional pound over the first pound. $7.00 for the first pound. Add $0.50 for each additional pound over the first pound.

So far I'm just trying to figure out the simple calculation for a letter.  I have code written to compute JUST THE FIRST LINE OF INSTRUCTIONS!  But I get 0.0 for every delivery charge.  This one's a little confusing so I hope I'm explaining it right.  I cannot use arrays or loops for this program.  Here's my driver class:

```
public class ExpressimoDelivery {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String pkg, service;
        int ounces;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the package type (letter or box): ");
        pkg = input.next();
        System.out.println("Enter the type of delivery service (P - for Priority, S - for Standard, TWO - for 2 Day): ");
        service = input.next();
        System.out.println("Please enter the weight of the package in ounces: ");
        ounces = input.nextInt();



        Delivery customer = new Delivery(pkg, service, ounces);
        customer.setPackage(pkg);
        customer.setService(service);
        customer.setWeight(ounces);

        System.out.println("You have chosen to mail a " + pkg + "\nand the cost"
                + " to mail a " + pkg + " weighing " + ounces + " ounces with " + service + " service is: "
                + customer.getTotal());
    }

}
```

And here's my Delivery Class:

```
public class Delivery {

    public static final float LETTER_PRIORITY = 12.00f;
    public static final float LETTER_STANDARD = 10.50f;
    public static final float BOX_PRIORITY = 15.75f;
    public static final float BOX_STANDARD = 13.75f;
    public static final float BOX_TWO_DAY = 7.00f;
    public static final float ADD_PRIORITY = 1.25f;
    public static final float ADD_STANDARD = 1.00f;
    public static final float ADD_TWODAY = 0.50f;

    public String pkg, service;
    public int weight = 0;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    public float fee;

    public Delivery(String pkg, String service, int weight){
        this.pkg = pkg;
        this.service = service;
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public void setPackage(String pkg){
        this.pkg = pkg;
    }

    public void setService(String service){
        this.service = service;
    }

    public void setWeight(int weight){
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public String getPackage(){
        if (! (pkg.equals("letter") || pkg.equals("box")))
        {
            System.out.println("ERROR: Unknown package type");
            pkg = "";
        }
        return pkg;
    }

    public String getService(){
        if (! (service.equals("P") || service.equals("S") || service.equals("TWO")));{
            System.out.println("ERROR: Unknown delivery type");
            service = "";
        }
        return service;
    }

    public float getWeight(){
        return weight;
    }

    public float getTotal(){
        if(pkg.equals("letter") && service.equals("P") && weight <= 8){
            fee = LETTER_PRIORITY;
        } else if(weight > 8) {
                    System.out.println("Package too large for a letter.  Please use box instead.");

        }
        return fee;
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's why you're getting 0.0 everytime.

You declared `public float fee;` which has a default value of 0.0.

In your `getTotal()` method, you return `fee` - note that here, you are returning the public float fee you declared above, and that you never changed it from the default value.

The problem is in your getTotal(). The main problem here is that you don't have an `else` after your `else if` statement. So what happens when you fail the first if statement, and you fail the else if? Nothing happens, and fee doesn't change, so you get a return of 0.0.

Solution:

```
public float getTotal(){

    if(pkg.equals("letter")) {
        if(weight > 8) {
            // quit early since it's too big
            // do your system.out.print here
            // return 8.8 since the size is too big; this is kind of
            // like an error code
            return 8.8;
        }

        if(service.equals("P")) {
            // service is priority
            fee = LETTER_PRIORITY;
        } else {
            // here, the service is not priority, so put the non priority letter calculations here
        }
    } else if (pkg.equals("box")) {
        // do your box fee checks and calculations here
    } else {
        // the pkg is not a box or a letter - something is wrong, give fee
        // a default value, for example 9.99 or whatever you want. 
        // make it something so that you KNOW that your pkg went into this 
        // loop and something went wrong
        fee = 9.99;
    }
}
```